# how to call to tableView from class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, instance-variables

Ive been having a lot of troubles deleting the cell from the tableView. I have 3 buttons in a sliding cell thats revealed when swiped over, the methods that call the swiping are in JBSliderViewController. In order to access the class method embedded in the homeViewController i created a instance method inside the JBSliderViewController `-(void)callDeleteFound` to call my +(void)deleteFound thats inside my homeViewController.

My issue now is i cant get access to my tableView to call `– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`
As well as `currentTable` is returning null

any suggestions?

inside JBSliderController

```
- (void)callDeletefound {
    [homeViewController deleteFound];

}
```

inside homeViewController

```
+ (void)deleteFound {
    NSUserDefaults *userSessionData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userID = [userSessionData stringForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *authKey = [userSessionData stringForKey:@"authKey"];
    NSString *appVersion = [userSessionData stringForKey:@"appVersion"];
    NSString *versionedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ios/%@/", appVersion];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"];
    NSString *postPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@deletefind.php", versionedURL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            userID, @"userid",
                            [MyClass friendID], @"friendid",
                            authKey, @"tempAuth",
                            nil];
    [httpClient postPath:postPath parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Removed from notifications"];
        NSMutableArray *notificationArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notificationsArray"];
        NSMutableArray *arrayThatYouCanRemoveObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:notificationArray];
        NSLog(@"%@", [MyClass cellNum]);
        NSInteger *num = [[MyClass cellNum] integerValue];
        [arrayThatYouCanRemoveObjects removeObjectAtIndex:num];
        [currentTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:openedCellIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [currentTable reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Fail" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the swipe affect you need to implement the table view delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, this will provide access to the swipe interaction for deletion. I typically provide an edit interaction as well for tableviews where deletion is possible since the swipe interaction tends to be a little bit hidden from users.

As an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [tableView beginUpdates];    
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];      
  }       
  [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Im trying to stay away from commitEditingStyle as im trying to delete the cell by pressing one of the 3 buttons inside the slider.

Comment: Can i call `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` inside my deleteFound method? Ive updated my post with the two methods.

Comment: Sorry guy, as per my knowledge without commitedit you can't delete row from tableview. if you get success than share with me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

NSArrays are inmmutable, that means you can't add or remove elements, hence your object doesn't have a `removeObjectAtIndex`: method.

- Check your property to see if its an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`.
- Check that the object in that pointer is in fact an `NSMutableArray`.
- To assign an `NSArray` to your variable first create an `NSMutableArray` from it using the   `arrayWithArray:` method.

Comment: Ive already solved that issue, please see my updated post. I need to acces the tableView... not its information.